# How does the current() method works in xslt and what its effects are

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I understand the current() in xslt 1.0?

Documentation:

[image]

**xml**

```
<xml>
  <listitems status="Yes" id="13" />
  <listitems status="No" id="12" />
</xml>
```

**xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="listitems">
    <!---The effects of using the period vs using current() -->
      <xsl:value-of select="//xml/listitems[@status=current()/@id]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="listitems">
    <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd be interested in a smaller example that can demo this better.

Comment: Your question is not clear. To understand the purpose of the `current()` function, read: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#misc-func --- Note that `document('')` selects the XSLT stylesheet document itself, so the entire expression selects nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure at all what you're trying to achieve with these samples.

Comment: What part of the specification don't you understand? There's clearly not much point in simply repeating it unless we know where you're having difficult.

Comment: It has no effects at all. It just returns the current node. This seems perfectly clear.

Comment: Can you show me a case where using current() makes a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting both "yes" and "no" in your output not because of the use of `.` or `current()`, but because you have two templates in your XSLT that match `listitems`

```
<xsl:template match="listitems">
```

This is an error according to the XSLT specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#conflict....

> It is an error if this [*The Conflict Resolution for Template Rules*] leaves more than one matching template rule. An
>   XSLT processor may signal the error; if it does not signal the error,
>   it must recover by choosing, from amongst the matching template rules
>   that are left, the one that occurs last in the stylesheet.

In your case, the XSLT processor is simply handing the last template in the stylesheet, which will output both "yes" and "no". If you delete the first template, you would get the same results.

If you want to see a case where `.` and `current()` are different, consider this XML

```
<xml>
  <lists>
      <listitems status="Yes" id="13" />
      <listitems status="No" id="12" />
  </lists>
  <tests>
     <test name="Bob" testid="1" itemid="13" />
     <test name="Kate" testid="2" itemid="12" />
  </tests>
</xml>
```

And this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tests" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:value-of select="./@name" />
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <!-- In this line, "." and "current()" are the same -->
    <xsl:value-of select="current()/@testid" />
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <!-- In this line, they are not the same. Only "current()" will give the result needed -->
    <xsl:value-of select="//xml/lists/listitems[@id = current()/@itemid]/@status" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, in this line, the `current()` function is being used in a condition that applies to a node

```
<xsl:value-of select="//xml/lists/listitems[@id = current()/@itemid]/@status" />
```

`current()` refers to the current node that was matched by the template; namely `test`

`.` refers to the "context" item, which in this case is the `listitems` element being selected.

Comment: Thank you so much for this example!